# SQL - Populating Group Table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, data-warehouse, dimensions

Given the following tables/relationships

[image]

**EDIT:** Which if populated using the SQL below should return this....

[image]

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Task.Name AS Expr1, dbo.Role.Name FROM dbo.Role INNER JOIN dbo.RoleTask ON dbo.Role.Id = dbo.RoleTask.RoleId INNER JOIN                       dbo.Task ON dbo.RoleTask.TaskId = dbo.Task.Id ORDER BY dbo.Task.Name, dbo.Role.Name
```

**Aim**

I'm trying to populate RoleGroup (The one that is just hanging there!) with the groups of roles defined by the many to many relationship between Role and Task, recognising that some may already be in the RoleGroup table.

**EDIT:** So, given the example results as above, this is what I need to see in RoleGroup (I've modified this since the original post to hopefully make it clearer as to what I am trying to acheive) ...

```
GroupId      RoleId
1            Plumber
2            Gardener
2            Topiary Guru
3            Electrician
4            Cleaner
4            Housekeeping Supervisor
4            Toilet Cleaning Specialist  
5            Housekeeping Supervisor
```

**Explanation of results**

Due to the fact that roles have been associated with certain Tasks, groups of roles can be identified.

In my example, "Cleaner, Housekeeping Supervisor, and Toilet Cleaning Specialist", have all been associated with "Toilet clean" tasks.  I can therefore say that that is a group, and would like to extract that information.

Likewise, "Housekeeping Supervisor" has been associated with "Toilet Inspection" tasks; and no other roles have. This means another new group should be extracted (2 - Housekeeping Supervisor).

If the "Housekeeping Supervisor" was associated with another task, and no other roles were, I wouldn't need to create another group, as it has already been recognised.

Oh, I'm trying to achieve this using SQL in SQL Server 2008.

Any tips or hints appreciated.

## SQL

```
USE TestDatabase
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Task](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Type] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Department](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Department] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RoleGroup](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Role](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Role] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RoleTask](
    [RoleId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TaskId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RoleTask] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RoleId] ASC,
    [TaskId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

```
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_Role_Department]    Script Date: 05/20/2011 17:56:49 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Role]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Role_Department] FOREIGN KEY([DepartmentId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Department] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Role] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Role_Department]
GO

/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_RoleTask_Role]    Script Date: 05/20/2011 17:56:49 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RoleTask]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_RoleTask_Role] FOREIGN KEY([RoleId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Role] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RoleTask] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_RoleTask_Role]
GO

/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_RoleTask_Task]    Script Date: 05/20/2011 17:56:49 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RoleTask]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_RoleTask_Task] FOREIGN KEY([TaskId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Task] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RoleTask] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_RoleTask_Task]
GO
```

```
/** DATA **/

INSERT INTO [Department] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (1, 'Housekeeping');
INSERT INTO [Department] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (2, 'Security');
INSERT INTO [Department] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (3, 'External Maintenance');
INSERT INTO [Department] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (4, 'Internal Maintenance');

INSERT INTO [Role] ([Id], [Name], [DepartmentId]) VALUES (1, 'Cleaner', 1);
INSERT INTO [Role] ([Id], [Name], [DepartmentId]) VALUES (2, 'Housekeeping Supervisor', 1);
INSERT INTO [Role] ([Id], [Name], [DepartmentId]) VALUES (3, 'Toilet Cleaning Specialist', 1);
INSERT INTO [Role] ([Id], [Name], [DepartmentId]) VALUES (4, 'Security Guard', 2);
INSERT INTO [Role] ([Id], [Name], [DepartmentId]) VALUES (5, 'Electrician', 4);
INSERT INTO [Role] ([Id], [Name], [DepartmentId]) VALUES (6, 'Plumber', 4);
INSERT INTO [Role] ([Id], [Name], [DepartmentId]) VALUES (7, 'Gardener', 3);
INSERT INTO [Role] ([Id], [Name], [DepartmentId]) VALUES (8, 'Topiary Guru', 3);

INSERT INTO [Task] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (1, 'Toilet Clean');
INSERT INTO [Task] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (2, 'Light Out');
INSERT INTO [Task] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (3, 'Blocked Sink');
INSERT INTO [Task] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (4, 'Toilet Inspection');
INSERT INTO [Task] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (5, 'Leaky Tap');
INSERT INTO [Task] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (6, 'Bush too bushy');
INSERT INTO [Task] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES (7, 'Mop Floor');

INSERT INTO [RoleTask] ([RoleId], [TaskId]) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO [RoleTask] ([RoleId], [TaskId]) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO [RoleTask] ([RoleId], [TaskId]) VALUES (3, 1);
INSERT INTO [RoleTask] ([RoleId], [TaskId]) VALUES (5, 2);
INSERT INTO [RoleTask] ([RoleId], [TaskId]) VALUES (6, 3);
INSERT INTO [RoleTask] ([RoleId], [TaskId]) VALUES (2, 4);
INSERT INTO [RoleTask] ([RoleId], [TaskId]) VALUES (6, 5);
INSERT INTO [RoleTask] ([RoleId], [TaskId]) VALUES (7, 6);
INSERT INTO [RoleTask] ([RoleId], [TaskId]) VALUES (8, 6);
INSERT INTO [RoleTask] ([RoleId], [TaskId]) VALUES (1, 7);
INSERT INTO [RoleTask] ([RoleId], [TaskId]) VALUES (2, 7);
INSERT INTO [RoleTask] ([RoleId], [TaskId]) VALUES (3, 7);
```

Comment: I've stared at this, but I just can't work out what you're trying to do. Given your sample data, what would the contents of RoleGroup look like?

Comment: @Philip Kelley: Thanks. I've edited the post to highlight what I'm after.  As mentioned, I need to be able to run the routine over and over to adding new groups, but not duplicate existing entries.  If it is still not clear let me know, and I'll try to explain it better.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `RoleGroup` table and how is it different from the `Role` table?

Comment: @Brent D: It will eventually contain a Group of Roles.  In the example I've given Group 1 consists of [Cleaner, Housekeeping Supervisor, and Toilet Cleaning Specialist], and Group 2 just [Housekeeping Supervisor] etc.  The roles is just all the individual roles available.

Comment: Why are the contents of Group 1 equal to [Cleaner, Housekeeping Supervisor, and Toilet Cleaning Specialist]? I do not understand the rule behind this.

Comment: @use: Because they have all been assigned to the same task (Toilet Clean). If the same three roles had also been assigned to another task (Leaky Tap) then I wouldn't want to create another (duplicate) group, because I have already identified that the group exists.

Comment: Hmm... sounds like you want to group together the tasks for a particular role into 'one' group... if so, why wouldn't you just have a groupID column in the RoleTask table? If you have a RoleGroup table like you mentioned, what would the groupIDs be used for? You're basically just grouping Roles together... what purpose does this serve if you're not using groupID somewhere? Specifically in your example, you have 'housekeeping supervisor' twice, with two different groupIDs... what does this mean?

Comment: @M.R - GroupId on a Role table wont do, as the role can belong to many groups. 

I've updated the question in an attempt to explain how the results should identified.

Comment: I am just not intelligent enough to understand this. Currently my understanding is that the RoleTask table is already exactly what you want.

Comment: Imagine that I want to break the relationship between Role and Task, and associate task with a RoleGroup. e.g Task "Toilet Clean" would be do'able by RoleGroup 1.  How can I generate the groups from the data already there?

Am I going mental, and missing the blindingly obvious?!? (Not too many posts answering that last bit please!!)

Comment: It still doesn't make sense - if you want to associate 'toilet clean' task with two different roles, then you would have it in the roleTask twice, and then optionally grouping them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm making perfect sense of your questions, but as the commenters have suggested you probably have a problem with your schema.

For one thing, a role group is a role hiding under a different name; the only difference based on your schema is that it doesn't necessarily belong to a department. But then again you could say the same of roles too: even in large-sized companies it's frequent to have a user/role that reports to multiple bosses and thus belongs to several departments.

So what you're really looking at is a group hierarchy. If you abstract things down the road, you'll be happy to be able to assign a task to multiple roles in one go. You could reasonably dump roles and role groups into a single table, roles, along with a role2role table that allows to relate them with each other: some roles assign other roles, but the other way around is not true; some roles belong to multiple role groups; and role groups have multiple groups; it's an oriented graph whose primary key will be a (ParentId, Id), both of which reference Roles(Id).

In addition, your RoleTask table is, for all intents and purposes, already answering your query. But you still want a new one called RoleGroup. And if I get the explanations you give in your question's comments, adding a new task and a new associated role automatically leads to a new role group. This injective property should hint that tasks too are roles hiding under a different name as well.

Further, note that some tasks can be decomposed in multiple individual tasks, and that these individual subtasks may be part of multiple larger tasks. This is an oriented graph as well.

At any rate, this is to say that you should consider merging all of these tables together. For the sake of being able to easily add foreign keys, you might want to keep them split in three, but if you do I'd suggest that Tasks and RoleGroup be trimmed to an Id field, which is both the primary key and a foreign key to Roles(Id).

By the same token, you might also want to look into the Department table and apply the same logic there. There might be a few extra details needed for it, e.g. a ManagerId, but at the end of the day its a role under a different name too: its main purpose is to group users together, and perhaps all users within a department ought to get some tasks in some cases. It fits right into the oriented graph described above.

Last, but not least, it might be worth pointing out that individual users (which do not show in your diagram but which are surely present in your schema) are roles in their own right too. It may very well be that a task is specifically assigned to an individual rather than a role or a group thereof. Plus, you never know when a manager wants to delegate his permissions to his secretary because he's on vacation at the end of the month.

Now, arguably, it is certainly possible to manage this entire mess using multitudes of tables and relationships between them, just like you're trying to do now. But you could also introduce two new table, say Perm (as in permissions) and PermPerm (as in permission assignments). And make the individual nodes (i.e. User, Dept, Role, Task) inherit from Perm. Doing so will allow you to manage your entire permission graph from a single table: PermPerm.

Oh, and if you've an hour, consider watching this video: [The ACL is dead](http://vimeo.com/2723800). It has interesting insights on permission management: